# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1444).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/community-promotion-ads-2017)

Answer (score 24):

[image: Mathematica support for the most advanced IDE]

Answer (score 23):

[image: Mathematica Packages]

Comment: The `https` thing seems dysfunctional

Comment: @belisarius It was supposed to be `http` - fixed it.

Answer (score 22):

[Browse through our unanswered questions! http://mma-se-ads.herokuapp.com/static/mathematica/unanswered.png](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/unanswered)

Comment: This is cool. Is there any way to adapt it to other sx-sites?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Sure. See my comment [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/community-promotion-ads-2014#comment5992_1168), for example. Send me a blank template with the appropriate design for your site, the font and colors and I'll upload it to my server

Answer (score 17):

[image: Pitfalls for new users]

Answer (score 14):

[image: MATLink – Seamlessly call MATLAB from Mathematica]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange]

Comment: Courtesy of [@squeamishossifrage](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1372/3808) from PPCG. (This ad replaces the ads from last year, in order to add a bit of variety.)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Comment: Have you considered updating this for the 2016 ad format?  http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/community-promotion-ads-2016

Answer (score 8):

[See all questions with active bounties http://mma-se-ads.herokuapp.com/static/mathematica/bounty.png](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: We have a site specific AD for that here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1248/5 Could you please replace the image here with the one from there? (It's auto-updating as well)

Comment: @rm-rf: Done. I didn't know that...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Support the FIRST Robotics proposal on Area51.SE!]